# How to prevent audio files and particle system from playing automatically when loading the game?

Tags: unity

I am using Unity. I have attached an audio-file (via Audio Source) to an empty object. I will play the game this plays automatically. The same is happens with the particle system.
I would like to know how to prevent this from occurring.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untick the Play on start tickbox, or something similar.

Please read the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html) before you start doing anythin in Unity or in any game engine!
Makes your life a whole lot easier!

Comment: Thanks that helped.